# Why is the program returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, sorting, return

Write a mySort function which takes in an array of integers, and should return an array of the inputted integers sorted such that the odd numbers come first and even numbers come last. 
So:
mySort([90, 45, 66, 'bye', '100.5'])
should return
[45, 66, 90, 100].

Here is my code:

```js
function mySort(array) {
  var strArray = [];
  var oddArray = [];
  var evenArray = [];
  var sortedArray = [];
  var arrayLength = array.length
  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 'string') {
      strArray = array[i].push();
    }
    if (Math.floor().array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      evenArray = array[i].push();
    }
    if (Math.floor().array[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      oddArray = array[i].push();
    }
  }

  sortedArray = sort(oddArray) + sort(evenArray);
}

console.log(mySort[90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5]);
```

Comment: Because you're not calling mySort. You need `mySort([` and nothing is being returned from the function. Apart from the other syntax errors in the function.

Comment: what happens with `100.5` should it become `100`? what is with `'bye'` should it be filtered out?

Comment: @Nina Scholz yes you are right, any strings in the array should be removed and any float should be made a whole number.

Comment: @Brahma Dev I have corrected that thanks but it's still not working as desired.

Comment: I mean, clearly, due to the explanation you gave, you understand how to call a function. So this is just a typo? `console.log(mySort[90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5]);`

Comment: `mySort[90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5]` is not a function call, but an access to a property of the function (with the last value `100.5`), which is `undefined`.

Comment: @Kevin B yes, thanks. I hope not to make such mistake next time.

Comment: @Nina Scholz thanks once more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several errors.

1. You didn't return:

   ```
   function mySort(array) {
       // ...
       return sortedArray;
   }
   ```
2. You should pass the parameter to Math.floor:

   ```
   Math.floor(array[i]);
   ```
3. You should pass the parameter to array.push:

   ```
   strArray.push(array[i]);
   evenArray.push(array[i]);
   oddArray.push(array[i]);
   ```
4. You should concat:

   ```
   sortedArray = oddArray.concat(evenArray);
   ```

Now it at least runs.

5. You should use typeof: (sorts string)

   ```
   if (typeof array[i] === 'string') {
       // ...
   }
   ```
6. You should use else if: (removes string)

   ```
   if (typeof array[i] === 'string') {
       // ...
   }
   else if (Math.floor(array[i]) % 2 === 0) {
       // ...
   }
   else if (Math.floor(array[i]) % 2 !== 0) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
7. Your for loop should end earlier: (removes `undefined`)

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
8. You should push the floor:

   ```
   evenArray.push(Math.floor(array[i]));
   oddArray.push(Math.floor(array[i]));
   ```
9. Finally, sort it in order [using a comparator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description):

   ```
   sortedArray.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; })
   ```

Solution:

```
function mySort(array) {
    var strArray = [];
    var oddArray = [];
    var evenArray = [];
    var sortedArray = [];
    var arrayLength = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (typeof array[i] === 'string') {
            strArray.push(array[i]);
        }
        else if (Math.floor(array[i]) % 2 === 0) {
            evenArray.push(Math.floor(array[i]));
        }
        else if (Math.floor(array[i]) % 2 !== 0) {
            oddArray.push(Math.floor(array[i]));
        }
    }

    sortedArray = oddArray.concat(evenArray);
    sortedArray.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    return sortedArray;
}

console.log(mySort([90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5])); // [45, 66, 90, 100]
```

Comment: Also he wants to know if an element is string, which he should do `if (typeof(array[i])`

Comment: Well, my objective is to help him with his question, not solve his homework.

Comment: @aaron it's returning something now but not what I want. It's not a homework and I will appreciate further pointers.thanks

Comment: @aaron it worked. thanks though I am still trying to wrap my head around the "sortedArray.sort(function (a, b) { return a > b});". I know it has to do with something on sorting I saw earlier online but I will appreciate it if you explain.

Comment: @aaron I am checking the points you gave now pls ignore my last comment. Thanks

Comment: please do not use a boolena result as return value for sort order. you still miss the negative values. the result is a non symetrical sort.

Comment: @danoseun I added a link on the comparator function. Hope it helps!

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for your feedback. I've fixed it :)

Comment: @NinaScholz Please retract your downvote if you're satisfied.

Comment: @aaron, it's not from me.

Answer (score 2):

- You have no `return` statement. JavaScript `function` syntax doesn't implicitly return the last expression, except to return `undefined` if no explicit return is present.
- You should `.concat()` the arrays. The `+` doesn't do what you seem to want.

  ```
  return sort(oddArray).concat(sort(evenArray));
  ```
- This condition is incorrect:

  ```
  if(array[i] === 'string'){
  ```
- You need `typeof` there to check the type of the member.

  ```
  if(typeof array[i] === 'string'){
  ```
- Your `.push()` calls are wrong. I guess you meant this:

  ```
  evenArray.push(array[i]);
  ```
- Your recursive calls should be using `mySort()` instead of `sort()`.
- `strArray` and `sortedArray` are essentially being ignored.
- `Math.floor()` expects an argument.

  ```
   Math.floor(array[i])
  ```
- Your loop condition is wrong. It should be `i < arrayLength`, not `<=`
- Your recursion has no escape clause
- Your initial call to `mySort` is not using parentheses to invoke it. It should be:

  ```
  console.log(mySort([/*...array items...*/]));
  ```
- Your `if` conditions should be using `else`. If it's a string, you don't need to test it again, assuming it is to be excluded. If it's not even, then you know it's odd, based on your criteria, so the last condition isn't needed.
- You apparently want to convert strings to numbers if possible, and converted to an integer. So instead of the `typeof` check, you could go ahead and convert it using `parseInt` or `+` or `Number`, and check if it's `NaN`, and if so, pass it over, and if not, make sure it's converted to an integer before testing it for odd/even.

---

Just to note, [*arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do have an implicit return when the function body consists of a single expression.

---

Here's a working example with the above corrections:

```js
function mySort(array) {
    var oddArray = [];
    var evenArray = [];
    var arrayLength = array.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var n = Math.floor(Number(array[i]));
        if (isNaN(n)) {
            continue;
        }
        
        if (n % 2 === 0 ){
            evenArray.push(n);
        } else {
            oddArray.push(n);
        }
    }

    return oddArray.length < 1 ? evenArray :
           evenArray.length < 1 ? oddArray : 
           mySort(oddArray).concat(mySort(evenArray));
}


console.log(mySort([90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5]));
```

Comment: Also the way he's doing Math.floor, and calling the Array.prototype.sort() function, also the way he's doing Array.prototype.push()...

Comment: @llama I have made those changes but it's still returning same thing

Comment: @Lixus: Yep, there were a bunch more too. It was the right overall logic, but mistakes everywhere.

Comment: ...oh wait, I thought he was also attempting a binary sort as well. If he wants to use `Array.prototype.sort`, then the recursion isn't needed. If a binary sort was desired, then the logic needs to change.

Comment: @llama the code returns [45, 90, 66, 100] instead of [45, 66, 90, 100]. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

With a simple improvement on @llama 's code, expected result is returned.

We just need to sort oddArray and evenArray individually.

```js
function mySort(nums) {
  'use strict'
    var array = nums
    var strArray = [];
    var oddArray = [];
    var evenArray = [];
    var sortedArray = [];
    var arrayLength = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (typeof array[i] === 'string') {
            strArray.push(array[i]);
        }
        else if (Math.floor(array[i]) % 2 === 0) {
            evenArray.push(Math.floor(array[i]));
        }
        else if (Math.floor(array[i]) % 2 !== 0) {
            oddArray.push(Math.floor(array[i]));
        }
    }
// sort oddArray
    oddArray.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
// sort evenArray
    evenArray.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
// make an array from both of them.
    sortedArray = oddArray.concat(evenArray);
    return sortedArray;
}
```